# sed command doesn't work with open command

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

I use `sed` to replace character`~` in string, and then open the folder of the path shown by this string on macOS.

```
#!/bin/bash
string="~/example"
echo $string | sed -r 's/~/\/JKFolder\/demo/'
open $string | sed -r 's/~/\/JKFolder\/demo/'
```

`Echo` can print the correct path `/JKFolder/demo/`, but `open` can't, it seems to run the first part of the string, which is the same as `open $string`.  `Sed` doesn't work in this command. Thank you.

Comment: Because you omit `echo`. You need `open $(sed -r 's/~/\/JKFolder\/demo/' <<< "$string")`. Or, `open "${string/\~/\/JKFolder\/demo}"`, no need using sed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you omit `echo` the `string` variable is not passed to `sed`, hence it does not work.

This would work:

```sh
open $(sed 's/~/\/JKFolder\/demo/' <<< "$string")
open $(echo "$string" | sed 's/~/\/JKFolder\/demo/')
open $(echo "$string" | sed 's,~,/JKFolder/demo,')
```

However, you do not really need `sed` in this case, you can just use

```sh
open "${string/\~/\/JKFolder\/demo}"
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/OzaTl7).

The `"${string/\~/\/JKFolder\/demo}"` is an example of a variable expansion, where the first occurrence of a `~` char is replaced with `/JKFolder/demo` string.